# Dialated Convolutions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

How can I use [dialated convolutions](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) in Tensorfow in a network exactly like the one described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) except that instead of using normal 5x5 receptive fields, i'm using 2-dialated 3x3 receptive fields (which should end up being 5x5, just with only 9 nonzero weights).

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: How to implement dialated convolutions in tensorflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tensorflow` you can use `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d()` to achieve the dilated convolutions, the param `rate` will define the dilation you want to apply.